# Ldap Entries Results

Tags: php, laravel, ldap

When I use `ldap_get_entries()` function, I get a multidimensional array with a lot of useless keys and values such as

```
array(
    'count' => 1234,
    0 => array(
        0 => 'first-name',
        'first-name' => array(
            'count' => 1,
            0 => 'Alex'
        ),
        ...
    ),
    ...
);
```

I would like to get a simple associative array such as:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'first-name' => 'Alex'
    )
)
```

It would be a lot simpler to manipulate and use. I used to create a function that creates an another array with such a format, but it is pretty complex and not perfect.

Is there a way to achieve this with LDAP own functions?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I am using **PHP**.

Comment: Add some more information to the question. What language you are using.

Comment: PHP, sorry, I forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

With the default LDAP-Extension you will not be able to retrieve an array as you'd like it to be.

One thing is that the returned array of `ldap_get_Entries()` returns the attributes inside each entry using an integer key and each of the attributes will then be inside the array with the attribute name in lowercase and the values for the attribute as array. That might be senseless when simply retrieving the first name of a user, but consider people with more than one name. They might have two attributes `first-name` each containing one of the names. A better example might be a phone number. There might be more than one phone number for a given person, so the result can be an array. To make things easier you will **always** get an array back.

So when you want something "easier to work with" you will have to write something like this gist: https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/536f75cb06209093375b

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is just what I did, but in a way that fits me. I just wondered if there is a way to do it with LDAP. I got the answer to that.